# Objective c program behaving differently with and without breakpoints (XCode)

Tags: ios, debugging, ios-simulator, xcode4.2

I am new to iOS development and i am facing an issue.

Putting breakpoints in my app before running the app in simulator is causing unexpected behavior.

If I put breakpoints in my app then I am not able to type in to text controls or click buttons i.e. it makes entire view read only.

If I disable the breakpoints, my app runs fine.

Any pointers to this issue will be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't hit a breakpoint when that happens?

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting a breakpoint which pauses execution of the main (UI) thread. Your application will not be able to process touch events when it is paused. Click the play button in Xcode to resume execution.

[image]